# Why the images are not displayed automatically?

Tags: java

good day, I am a beginner with the language of java, I'm trying to control an animation. I have a problem with the animation, because the program doesn't display the images. I create an array of JLabels and then I set 72 images to this. I create a frame and then I add 2 buttons, a first image with a charged battery and then a slider bar, don't put attention to the slider bar because I'm not using it yet. I want to create 2 animations, when I press the button called "cargar", the program must hide the actual image and then display the next image at the same position, then the program must wait a short delay and then it must repeat the same actions in a loop, so in the frame must run an animation where the animation must show how the battery is charging. When someone press the button called "descargar", the program must display the same images but in opposite way, so that the animation must show how the battery is discharging. Watch the video to see the problem more clearly. I can't get that the program display all the image automatically, it only display the last image,but it is strange that the program can show every image without a loop but it isn't automatic, I must to press the buttons many times. I need your help to solve the problem, may some one give me a suggestion, and maybe some tips to reduce the lines of code, thank you for your  attention.

link of the vieo:
http://youtu.be/w6pINh-4TGM

here is the code:

```
//Referring to the package
package programa;

//imported classes
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

//begins subclass of JFrame and implements ActionListener and Runnable interfaces
public class Intento3 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable{
    //global variables declaration
    //creating an array of JLabels (72 JLabels)
    JLabel[] labels = { new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel(),
    new javax.swing.JLabel()};
    //creating JButtons
    JButton jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    JButton jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    //creating JSlider
    JSlider miSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 50, 0);
    //creating a boolean variable
    boolean carga;
    //creating integer variables
    int x = 0;
    int i;

    //start the program
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
       //creating an object of the created class
       Intento3 curso = new Intento3();
       //calling the method "cuadro" of the created class
       curso.cuadro();
    }

    //start the method "cuadro"
    public void cuadro(){
         //title of the frame
         setTitle("Animacion bateria");
         //size of the frame
         setSize(350, 350);
         //statement to close the frame
         setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         //declaration to prohibit the change of size of the frame
         setResizable(false);
         //made the frame visible
         setVisible(true);
        //set images to the array of JLabels 
        labels[0].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila1.jpg")));
        labels[1].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila2.jpg")));
        labels[2].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila3.jpg")));
        labels[3].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila4.jpg")));
        labels[4].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila5.jpg")));
        labels[5].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila6.jpg")));
        labels[6].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila7.jpg")));
        labels[7].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila8.jpg")));
        labels[8].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila9.jpg")));
        labels[9].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila10.jpg")));
        labels[10].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila11.jpg")));
        labels[11].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila12.jpg")));
        labels[12].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila13.jpg")));
        labels[13].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila14.jpg")));
        labels[14].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila15.jpg")));
        labels[15].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila16.jpg")));
        labels[16].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila17.jpg")));
        labels[17].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila18.jpg")));
        labels[18].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila19.jpg")));
        labels[19].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila20.jpg")));
        labels[20].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila21.jpg")));
        labels[21].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila22.jpg")));
        labels[22].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila23.jpg")));
        labels[23].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila24.jpg")));
        labels[24].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila25.jpg")));
        labels[25].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila26.jpg")));
        labels[26].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila27.jpg")));
        labels[27].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila28.jpg")));
        labels[28].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila29.jpg")));
        labels[29].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila30.jpg")));
        labels[30].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila31.jpg")));
        labels[31].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila32.jpg")));
        labels[32].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila33.jpg")));
        labels[33].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila34.jpg")));
        labels[34].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila35.jpg")));
        labels[35].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila36.jpg")));
        labels[36].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila37.jpg")));
        labels[37].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila38.jpg")));
        labels[38].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila39.jpg")));
        labels[39].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila40.jpg")));
        labels[40].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila41.jpg")));
        labels[41].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila42.jpg")));
        labels[42].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila43.jpg")));
        labels[43].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila44.jpg")));
        labels[44].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila45.jpg")));
        labels[45].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila46.jpg")));
        labels[46].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila47.jpg")));
        labels[47].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila48.jpg")));
        labels[48].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila49.jpg")));
        labels[49].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila50.jpg")));
        labels[50].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila51.jpg")));
        labels[51].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila52.jpg")));
        labels[52].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila53.jpg")));
        labels[53].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila54.jpg")));
        labels[54].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila55.jpg")));
        labels[55].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila56.jpg")));
        labels[56].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila57.jpg")));
        labels[57].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila58.jpg")));
        labels[58].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila59.jpg")));
        labels[59].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila60.jpg")));
        labels[60].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila61.jpg")));
        labels[61].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila62.jpg")));
        labels[62].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila63.jpg")));
        labels[63].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila64.jpg")));
        labels[64].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila65.jpg")));
        labels[65].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila66.jpg")));
        labels[66].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila67.jpg")));
        labels[67].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila68.jpg")));
        labels[68].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila69.jpg")));
        labels[69].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila70.jpg")));
        labels[70].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila71.jpg")));
        labels[71].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenesintento3/pila72.jpg")));
        //set properties of JSlider
        miSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        miSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        //set the titles of the buttons
        jButton1.setLabel("Cargar");
        jButton2.setLabel("Descargar");
        //set a listener to the buttons
        jButton1.addActionListener(this);
        jButton2.addActionListener(this);

            //add image "pila1" to the frame
            add(labels[0]);
            //set the exact position of the image "pila1"
            this.setLayout(null);
            Insets insets = this.getInsets();
            Dimension size = labels[1].getPreferredSize();
            labels[0].setBounds(70,50,196,102);       
            labels[0].setVisible(true);          

            //add button1 to the frame
            add(jButton1);
            //set the exact position of the button1
            this.setLayout(null);
            Insets insets1 = this.getInsets();
            Dimension size1 = jButton1.getPreferredSize();
            jButton1.setBounds(40,200,73,30);       
            jButton1.setVisible(true);         

            //add button1 to the frame
            add(jButton2);
            //set the exact position of the button2
            this.setLayout(null);
            Insets insets2 = this.getInsets();
            Dimension size2 = jButton2.getPreferredSize();
            jButton2.setBounds(200,200,94,30);       
            jButton2.setVisible(true);      

            //set properties of JSlider
            miSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
            miSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
            //add JSlider to the frame
            add(miSlider);
            //set the exact position of the JSlider
            this.setLayout(null);
            Insets insets3 = this.getInsets();
            Dimension size3 = miSlider.getPreferredSize();
            miSlider.setBounds(70,240,200,40);       
            miSlider.setVisible(true);            
    }

    //start the method "actionPerformed"
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        //get the argument of the buttons
        Object fuente = e.getSource();
        //if the button1 is pressed...
        if(fuente == jButton1){
            //start the "b1apretado" method
            b1apretado();
            //start the execution thread
            run();             
        }
        //if the button2 is pressed...
        if(fuente == jButton2){
            //start the "b2apretado" method
            b2apretado(); 
            //start the execution thread
            run();           
        }                
    }

    //start the execution thread 
    @Override
    public void run() {

            //if boolean variable is true...
            if(carga == true){      

            while( x > 0){
            //add image to the frame    
            add(labels[x-1]);
            //set the exact position of the image
            labels[x-1].setBounds(70,50,196,102);
            //hide the last image
            labels[x].setVisible(false);    
            //set visible the image
            labels[x-1].setVisible(true);     
            //reduce by one the variable "x"
            --this.x;
            //set a delay
            try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){} 

            }
            }

            //if boolean variable is false...
            if(carga == false){

            while( x < 71)   {
            //add image to the frame   
            add(labels[x+1]);
            //set the exact position of the image
            labels[x+1].setBounds(70,50,196,102);
            //hide the last image
            labels[x].setVisible(false); 
            //set visible the image
            labels[x+1].setVisible(true);
            //increase by one the variable "x"
            ++this.x;
            //set a delay
            try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){} 

            }
      }         
    }

    //start the "b1apretado" method
    public void b1apretado(){
        //set the boolean variable as true
        carga = true;
    }

    //start the "b2apretado" method
    public void b2apretado(){
        //set the boolean variable as false
        carga = false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please create a MCVE - a **MINIMAL**, Complete and Verifiable example. I suggest learning about the `for` loop so that you can create your labels in icons in 3 lines of code instead of 72 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your actionPerformed method, we can see you isn't calling the run method in a separate [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). Calling Runnable.run() will execute run method in the current thread. You need create a Thread object and call start method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
    Object fuente = e.getSource();
    if(fuente == jButton1){
        b1apretado();                     
    }
    if(fuente == jButton2){   
        b2apretado();                     
    } 
    Thread thread=new Thread(this);
    thread.start();                  
}
```

However, this approach could cause exceptions, as you are updating the GUI in your own thread. A better approach would be use SwingWorker, as you can see in this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/multi-threading-java-swing).

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly creating a Thread object and then using and then using the method start ()

Comment: @user3550817, `It works perfectly creating a Thread object`, it works until it doesn't work and then you will spend hours trying to debug a random problem. You have been told twice NOT to use a Thread.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial's link I added in my answer. As @camickr said, you can have troubles using Thread this way, Swing has some classes specific for working with multithread that treats some concurrency problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get that the program display all the image automatically, it only display the last image

You are not using Threads correctly. Invoking the run() method is not how to start a Thread. Also, the Thread.sleep() causes the Event Dispatch Thread to sleep so the GUI can't repaint itself until all the code in the loop has been executed.

Some suggestions:

1. Don't keep an array or JLabels. Instead keep an Array of Icons. Then you just create a single label that you display on the GUI. For your animation you simple change the Icon of the label by using the `setIcon(...)` method.
2. Don't attempt to use Threads. Instead you should use a Swing Timer for the animation. You start the Timer and every time the Timer fires you change the Icon of the label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a simple animation example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it with the timer